# How to convert from android.graphics.Bitmap to javascript ImageData in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript, tensorflow.js

Is there any existing libraries that I can easily convert a **android.graphics.Bitmap** object to Javascript **ImageData**?  I am using NativeScript to build an app that takes Bitmap from camera and use tfjs for further processing.  The tfjs library requires to use ImageData as an input.

In the Android part, I have the android.graphics.Bitmap object ready, which is an output from my **TextureView**.

```
var bitmap = myTextureView.getBitmap();
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView#getBitmap(int,%20int)

In the Tensorflow part, I need to first convert it into **ImageData** type.

```
const segmentation = await net.segmentPerson(img);
```

https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/body-pix

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData

Answer (score 0):

**NativeScript !== Browser**

{N} just gives you a JS runtime, it's not a Browser or WebView. It's just a way for you to reuse your web skills but you can't expect all browser dependent APIs to work here.

Thats being said, you have to take a closer look at the [ImageSource](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_image_source_) module which is kind of alternate for ImageData here. But still it may not work with tfjs and I doubt tfjs works at all with {N} without significant efforts.

I see that tfjs is trying to support ReactNative, not sure how far they have got. But I presume they do it by exposing C++ APIs into native app, the same could be ported into {N} but that would require significant efforts.

So I would suggest you to find a plugin Or native equivalent on iOS / Android, which you may directly be able to use in your project.